# Telerik controls from radtreeview: How to get count of all nodes under parent node and edit contents of treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radtreeview

I'm trying to create a user control which automatically populates the contents of radtree view in text boxes. The user control should allow me to get the count of all the nodes under the parent node and it should allow me to edit the contents of the treeview through the text box in the user control and those changes should reflect in the tree. Can someone help?

**Usercontrol xaml code**:

```
UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeviewUControl"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="TreeviewUControl.UserControl1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
              d:DesignWidth="300" Height="350">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- <Label Content="this is test"  Name="testLbl" /> -->
        <Label x:Name="Name" Grid.Row="0" Content="Name" Margin="10"/>
        <Label x:Name="Services" Grid.Row="1" Content="Services" Margin="10" />
        <Label x:Name="Scripts" Grid.Row="2" Content="Scripts" Margin="10" />
        <Label x:Name="Scenarios" Grid.Row="3" Content="Scenarios" Margin="10" />
        <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="ProjectName" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10"  Text="RadWatermarkTextBox" Width="150" TextChanged="projectnameChanged"/>
        <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="radWatermarkTextBox1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Text="RadWatermarkTextBox" Width="150" />
        <telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox x:Name="radWatermarkTextBox2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3"  Text="RadWatermarkTextBox" Width="150" />
        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButton" Content="Save changes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37"  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Click="Savechanges" Margin="10,117,0,-103"/>
        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButton1" Content="Export" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37"  Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" Margin="38,117,0,-103"/>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**mainwindowXaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string selectedPath;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
   private void treenodeclick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
        Stakname.Children.Add(uc);
        selectedPath = RadTreeView.SelectedValuePath;
        uc.ProjectName.Text = RadTreeView.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
```

Mainwindow xaml

Comment: Mainwindow xaml code is missing

Comment: <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="White">
       <telerik:RadTreeView x:Name="RadTreeView">
            <telerik:RadTreeViewItem x:Name="RadTreeViewItem"
                                 Header="MyItems"  Selected="treenodeclick" Grid.Row="0"  >
            <telerik:RadTreeViewItem x:Name="RadTreeViewItem1"
                                 Header="Car"  
            </telerik:RadTreeViewItem><telerik:RadTreeViewItem x:Name="RadTreeViewItem2"
                                 Header="cycle"  
            </telerik:RadTreeViewItem>
        </telerik:RadTreeView>